# How to release microphone from pocketsphynx in Android

Tags: android, microphone, android-audiomanager, android-audiorecord, pocketsphinx-android

I'm using pocketsphynx library on Android for keyword spotting, and it serves its purpose great. However, when I am trying to release microphone to make use of it in another component of the app, I am unable to do so. I get the following error in logcat:

```
12-11 10:19:55.827 255-30344/? I/AudioFlinger_Threads: AudioFlinger's thread 0xa6cc0000 ready to run
12-11 10:19:55.849 255-31292/? W/APM::AudioPolicyManager: startInput(17675) preempting low-priority input 17671
12-11 10:19:55.859 255-29587/? W/AudioALSAStreamManager: -routingInputDevice(), input_device == AUDIO_DEVICE_NONE(0x0), return
12-11 10:19:55.924 27054-1900/? W/AudioRecord: dead IAudioRecord, creating a new one from obtainBuffer()
12-11 10:19:55.925 255-30344/? W/AudioALSAStreamManager: -routingInputDevice(), input_device == current_input_device(0x80000004), return
12-11 10:19:55.927 255-30346/? I/AudioFlinger_Threads: AudioFlinger's thread 0xaa880000 ready to run
12-11 10:19:55.930 255-31292/? W/APM::AudioPolicyManager: stopInput() unknown input 17671
12-11 10:19:55.930 255-31292/? W/APM::AudioPolicyManager: releaseInput() releasing unknown input 17671
12-11 10:19:55.931 255-953/? W/APM::AudioPolicyManager: startInput(AUDIO_SOURCE_HOTWORD) invalid, already started high-priority input 17675
12-11 10:19:55.931 27054-1900/? W/AudioRecord: restoreRecord_l() failed status -38
12-11 10:19:55.934 27054-1900/? E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error -38 during AudioRecord native read
12-11 10:19:55.951 27054-1900/? E/AudioProvider: audioRecord read failed
                                                 com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393221 | not open
                                                     at com.google.android.libraries.assistant.hotword.a.a(SourceFile:67)
                                                     at com.google.android.libraries.assistant.hotword.b.run(SourceFile:30)
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269)
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

This happens when I'm attempting to use `getUserMedia` from `WebView`. Before doing so, I am calling

```
recognizer.cancel();
```

from my Activity, but that doesn't seem to help.

I also tried using `.stop()`, `.removeListener(...)` APIs, but the issue still remains. Please suggest if there is a way to release a hold on a mic that pocketsphinx is making, so that other components of the app can use mic again.

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE 1:** Added more logs and looked at Android code for [AudioPolicyManager](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/1b4d229ee6b2abef871bcfcd30e0f1d7a1e42afb/services/audiopolicy/AudioPolicyManager.cpp). It seems like two processes (`31292` and `953`) were trying to compete by doing `startInput` call, and one (`31292`) shut down another (`953`). Obviously, I may be misinterpreting the log.

**UPDATE 2:** I looked into pocketsphynx [`SpeechRecognizer.shutdown`](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-android/blob/master/src/main/java/edu/cmu/pocketsphinx/SpeechRecognizer.java) method and found that this is *the* method that actually releases the `AudioRecord` object. By trial-end-error I managed to figure out how to call `shutdown` and not crash the app (it has to happen in onResult, after all the listeners are removed). After that, my another component started to work. I did not yet have a chance to confirm whether or not I can re-start keyword spotting after `shutdown`. If re-initialization is required after that (which takes a lot of time), that's not going to be an acceptable workaround.

**UPDATE 3:** I confirmed that `shutdown` is not necessary to release a hold on a mic. I managed to make my other component after just calling `stop` API. The key seems to be that stopping pocketsphinx takes a bit of time, and the other component should wait for that. The event I used, that worked for me was `onResult`. At that point another component is already able to get a hold of a new `AudioRecord`. I still haven't tried re-starting pocketsphinx after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I got it to work. Calling `SpeechRecognizer.shutdown` is indeed unnecessary. I was able to use `SpeechRecognizer.stop` API while making sure to wait for the last result to come in in `onResult` callback of my `RecognitionListener` implementation. After that I am able to call `getUserMedia` browser API and it successfully gets a hold of a mic.

`onResult` code in my `RecognitionListener` implementation:

```
recognizer.removeListener(listener);
```

I also was able to confirm that re-starting recognition is easy, I just needed to do the following:

```
recognizer.addListener(listener);
recognizer.addKeyphraseSearch(KWS_SEARCH, KEYPHRASE);
recognizer.startListening(KWS_SEARCH);
```

*Note:* I am stopping the recognizer in a separate thread similarly to how recognizer was instantiated, but I have not confirmed whether or not it is necessary.

Comment: i was enable to stop the recognizer after recognizer.cancel(), recognizer.stop and clearing all the listeners.
Then i wrapped onStop in a separate thread and it worked. 
Thanks @shalom-aleichem